# Why won't Python integer input check correctly?

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is my code:

```
Sens = input("""Sensitivity (MIN SENS 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 MAX SENS): """)
if not Sens == 0 or Sens == 1 or Sens == 2 or Sens == 3 or Sens == 4 or Sens == 5:
    print("Invalid: [{}]".format(Sens))
    print("Defaulting to 1")
```

It keeps outputting "Invalid" even though I type 1, 2, 3, 4 or 5 (it does work when i type 0).
Maybe this is really stupid but what am I doing wrong?

I have tried: making everything strings (input and checks), making everything int (input and checks), I have even tried making the input like this:
`str(int(input = ...))`, also didn't work

Comment: `if Sens not in ['0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5']:`

Comment: @It_is_Chris Why a list of strings instead of a set of ints?

Comment: @wjandrea because of the input: `Sens = input("""Sensitivity (MIN SENS 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 MAX SENS): """)` the OP is not converting it to an int: `Sens = int(input("""Sensitivity (MIN SENS 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 MAX SENS): """))`

Comment: @It_is_Chris So convert it...

Comment: @wjandrea The OP can if he/she/they want to.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help everyone!, I have found the answer and accepted it.   
never expected so many people to actually be nice and help and explain it, have an awesome day everyone! (especially want to thank: AziMez for the answer, @wjandrea for the edits, spelling improvements, and help in the comments and It_is_Chris for also helping everyone in the comments, you guys are awesome!)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

1. Adding `int()` to convert input from **str** to **int**
2. Adding **parentheses** to the logic phrase.

```
Sens = int(input("""Sensitivity (MIN SENS 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 MAX SENS): """))
if not (Sens == 0 or Sens == 1 or Sens == 2 or Sens == 3 or Sens == 4 or Sens == 5):
    print("Invalid: [{}]".format(Sens))
    print("Defaulting to 1")
```

As well, you can replace this long line:

```
if not (Sens == 0 or Sens == 1 or Sens == 2 or Sens == 3 or Sens == 4 or Sens == 5):
```

by this one:

```
if Sens not in range(6):
```

Comment: Couldn't you use a try and except call instead of the weird one line ```if not``` statement

Comment: nit: `if Sens >=6 or Sens < 0` would be more optimal than `not in range(6)`

Comment: @BrodyCritchlow I'm no python pro, but expecting an error and working off that if you can also just fix the code seems weird

Comment: @OneCricketeer Actually, [those are equivalent in Python 3](/a/30081318/4518341)! Provided that `Sens` is an integer, of course.

Comment: @Frostbite You're right, try-except wouldn't really make sense in this case. I'm not even sure what error Brody would expect to catch.